# django rest + react js how can I access directly the url of react route?

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework

My project has django-rest framework backend api server and reactjs frontend.

there is index.html of reactjs file in django static/file directory.
So, I can access the react page by the url "backend_url.com/static/index.html".

problem is I want to access the url of react router. 
"backend_url.com/static/index.html/public/log-in-page/" like this. to go directly to react log-in page.

but, the server try to find "static/index.html/public/log-in-page/" directory. so It will fail.

Finally, what I want to develop is to go directly the specific react page and pass over parameters by the url.

how can I reach that?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to configure your webserver so that it serves `index.html` regardless of the rest of the URL. Depending on your webserver, this will done one way or another.

However, if you are using Django, I suggest that you use Django views to render your page. You could be saving your React page as a template, and render the template from the view.

```py
# urls.py
from django.urls import re_path

url_patterns = [
  re_path(r'^/your/app/?.*', views.app)
]
```

```py
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def app(request):
  return render(request, 'index.html')
```